# Web project not loading after installing VS2012

Tags: .net

I have installed Visual studio 2012 ultimate version and Im trying open an existing solution built using 2012 by one of my colleages.
All other projects load except the Web project.
The error I get is

D:\Projects\WebUI.vbproj : error  : The Web Application Project WebUI is configured to use IIS.  Unable to access the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS web sites on your machine.

I haven't explicity installed any version of the framework.
Pls let me know of a solution if anyone has come accross this issue.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by running my VS2012 as admin.
Thanks.